# How to match regex in java

Tags: java, android, regex, textwatcher

I want a pattern like this: `GJ-16-RS-1234` and I have applied following patterns but they are not working.

My regex patterns are:

```
String str_tempPattern = "(^[A-Z]{2})\\-([0-9]{2})\\-([A-Z]{1,2})\\-([0-9]{1,4}$)";

String str_tempPattern = "(^[A-Z]{2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([A-Z]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,4})$";

String str_tempPattern = "^[A-Z]{2}\\-[0-9]{1,2}\\-[A-Z]{1,2}\\-[0-9]{1,4}$";
```

And I am using text watcher to check for any change in the `aftertextchange()`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(str_tempPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    if (m.find()){

    }
```

Comment: Can you should us what you are matching it from?

Comment: i am matching this : GJ-16-RS-1234

Comment: from what other text

Comment: I am pasing this string and matching with those regex patterns mentioned above...

Comment: @user3138859 your regex works for me. Show us the full code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have mentioned total three patterns... which one working for you...

Comment: Are you expecting it to return you back `GJ-16-RS-1234` after being matched?

Comment: all https://regex101.com/r/dR8wY2/1, https://regex101.com/r/dR8wY2/2 , https://regex101.com/r/dR8wY2/3

Comment: @hwnd i am just returning boolean . I am calling the method from afterTextChanged() of textwatcher

Comment: did you want the return type to be bool? Then use matches method. `string.matches("[A-Z]{2}\\-[0-9]{1,2}\\-[A-Z]{1,2}\\-[0-9]{1,4}");`

Comment: @AvinashRaj How to use that link of regex101.com I have mentioned the regex expression and written test string ...but what to do after that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the condition using  `matches` method.

```
if (string.matches("[A-Z]{2}\\-[0-9]{1,2}\\-[A-Z]{1,2}\\-[0-9]{1,4}")) 
{
        // Yes it matches
}
else
{
       // No it won't
}
```